# MongoError: not authorized on db to execute command? When connection with socket.io

Tags: mongodb, socket.io

I can't connect to my mongodb from socket.io.
When I run my server.js it says that it is connected with mongodb and that it is connected to a socket but then it shows the error

```
MongoError: not authorized on db to execute command find.
```

I have loged in as an admin user into the mongo admin database, then went to the "chat" db and there created a new user in the database with the role "readWrite" like this.

```
use chat
```

and then:

```
db.createUser({user: "testuser", pwd: "testuser", roles: [{role: "readWrite", db: "chat" }]})
Successfully added user: {
    "user" : "testuser",
    "roles" : [
        {
            "role" : "readWrite",
            "db" : "chat"
        }
    ]
}
```

The user gets created.
And when I test it with `db.auth("testuser","testuser")` I get a 1.
I then exit and go to my bin folder and there I write:`mongo.exe -u testuser -p testuser chat;`

And then it connects to `mongodb://127.0.0.1:127017/chat`

I then open a new prompt and go to my folder where I have the server.js that connects with the db and run it, it then first says that the server is running and that it is connected with the mongodb.

When I the go to my chat page and load it then it says that: MongoError not authorized...

I connect my server.js file like this

```
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
server.listen(port);
console.log('Server running *:'+port);

var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

//mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/chat', function(err){
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/chat', function(err){
```

I don´t know what Im missing, I have followed the docs on mongodb and looked all over the net, but not sure where I go wrong.

Any input really appreciated thanks.

When I load the chat page and look in the console I get this error.

```
https://manmade.se:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=Lceu0Ot&sid=wbFhDl7yylt4_4a1AAAA net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

index_webb.html:1 WebSocket connection to 'wss://manmade.se:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=wbFhDl7yylt4_4a1AAAA' failed: WebSocket is closed before the connection is established.
```

Comment: Are you sure you are connecting to the right port?

Comment: Yes, I had it working before but then I reinstalled mongodb and now I can´t get it to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error seems to suggest that through your program you are not authenticating on the right database.

When connecting from the shell, in your particular case, this would result in an error:

```
mongo -u test -p test
```

you would have to specify the chat database:

```
mongo chat -u test -p test
```

I don't think it is a socket error because you are connecting, the error message seems to suggest that you are just not authenticating on the right database (in this case the chat database)

Comment: Ok, thanks. So when I login I have to first log in as admin to the admin db? I have worked all day with this and Im start to be really confused now, not knowing what I have tested and not.

Comment: With what user am I suppose to connect with? Any that has readWrite permission?

Comment: Ok, so I loged in as admin and the:use chat and there I created a new user with "readWrite" in the "chat" db. It was created as it should. and when I test with db.auth("testuser","testuser") I get 1. I then tried standing at the bin folder: mongo -u testuser -p testuser chat; And then I get an error saying that ; is missing haha...

Comment: you can connect with any user that has readWrite permission. Even though your user "test" has read write permissions in the chat db, was the actual user created in the admin database or the chat database?

Comment: I made a new one just now, and I loged in as admin and then I went to the chat db with use chat and there I created a new user. I have updated my question with the latest I did just now.

Comment: ok, in the code that is failing I see that you are connecting to the chat db, where are you specifying the username and password that you're conecting with?

Comment: Im not sure haha, I have been at is for 16 hours now and my head is spinning. I connect with localhost and both the mongodb and the connecting server.js file is on the same server? I connect with this:mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/chat', function(err){...

Comment: I don´t know where to find the username and password, its that created in any of the mongoose files perhaps, I have no idea right now.

Comment: ok, so this is the problem you're just connecting to the database without specifying username and password. try replacing mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/chat'.... with
mongoose.connect('mongodb://testuser:yourpassword@127.0.0.1:27017/chat',

while putting in the correct password of course

Comment: THANK YOU SOOO MUCH!! It seams to work now. Thats what I have be thinking was so strange, that I did´t specify the username and password anywhere. And very strange that I had it working before without it!? Ok, so jus one last question. Im trying to connect from my home mac with mongohub, with host:manmade.se and port:27017 and then the username and password to db:chat, but it is off course not connecting ;-) Do you know why? Thanks again, so much!!

Comment: great glad it works. Can you post the command you are using to connect?

Comment: Im not sure I understand what you mean? When I connect inside my server? I get this error now when trying to connect with mongohub:{ ok: 0.0, errmsg: "auth failed", code: 18, codeName: "AuthenticationFailed" }

Comment: hmm I think you have to specify the database here. I'm not familiar with mongohub syntax but see if there is an option to specify the database and specify the chat database there

Comment: Yes thats what Im doing, or trying at least ;-) This info is in mongohub connection prompt: host:manmade.se and port:27017 and then the username and password and then db:chat .Mongohub was the only free ui I found for mongodb. Do you know any other maybe?

Comment: why not try using the good old mongo shell? its always been reliable for me

Comment: Yes, but Im not so used to work with the terminal, I like a ui to see the posts in the db :-)

Comment: I would use MongoDB Compass then. https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/tools/administration-interfaces/

Comment: Well Dan, haha. It is working as long as I have the terminal where I start the server.js file. The one where I have the mongoose.connect('mongodb://testuser:yourpassword@127.0.0.1:‌​27017/chat',. Why is this happening? If I try to start the mongodb with net start MongoDB it say its running. And if I run the server.js file it starts again. 16 hours of problems today, I have to go to bed, but if you can think of anything I really appreciate it, thanks a lot for you help Dan.

Comment: The error I get is: https://manmade.se:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LcffHcP net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT